# Find if a user is part of some distribution lists

Tags: powershell, nested, distribution-list

I want to get a script working in powershell which takes a user's email and look it up against a few distribution lists to see if the user is a part of any of them. It should also check the **nested distribution groups** if any under the main distribution lists.

here's what I have but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated, I am fairly new to this.

```
# Prompt for user email address
$UserEmail = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the user email address'

# Read the CSV file
$DistributionLists = Import-Csv -Path '.\DLs.csv'

# Loop through each Distribution List
foreach ($DL in $DistributionLists) {
    # Get List of Distribution Group Members
    $GroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL -ResultSize Unlimited

    # Loop through each member
    foreach ($Member in $GroupMembers) {
        # Check if the user's email address matches
        if ($Member.PrimarySmtpAddress -eq $UserEmail) {
            # Output the matches
            Write-Output "User $UserEmail is a part of $($DL.Name)"
        }
    }
}
```

but i get below error on execution:

```
Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.DistributionGroupMemberIdParameter". Error: "Parameter values of type Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.DistributionGroupMemberIdParameter can't be empty. Specify a value, and try again.
Parameter name: identity"
At C:\Users\abcd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA_hrt0empv.vlz\tmpA_hrt0empv.vlz.psm1:1087 char:13
+             Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=BNxxxxxx5601,RequestId=abcdef5-1e51-d5f0-2a56-77b30f23bf3a,TimeStamp=Thu, 09 Feb 2023 14:04:01 GMT],Write-ErrorMessage
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXIQi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error statement informs us "-Identify $DL" is empty; $DL returns the entire object row and not just the name to be matched.  To correct, refactor to $DL.DistributionLists where "DistributionLists" is the column header in the imported CSV file.

As we confirmed together you have already imported ExchangeOnlineManagement and made the connected to Exchange Online.... I've kept these in the code below for future reader reference.

```
# Pearl-script below:
# Import the ExchangeOnlineManagement module
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

# Connect to Exchange Online
Connect-ExchangeOnline

# Prompt for user email address
$UserEmail = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the user email address'

# Read the CSV file
$DistributionLists = Import-Csv -Path '.\DLs.csv'

# Loop through each Distribution List
foreach ($DL in $DistributionLists) {
    # Get List of Distribution Group Members
    $GroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL.DistributionLists -ResultSize Unlimited

    # Loop through each member
    foreach ($Member in $GroupMembers) {
        # Check if the user's email address matches
        if ($Member.PrimarySmtpAddress -eq $UserEmail) {
            # Output the matches
            Write-Output "User $UserEmail is a part of $($DL.DistributionLists)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was connected to exchange online and had the proper csv file. still i created a new csv file and re-connected to exO to be sure, but the same error.

Comment: Have you made sure the Name column in the DLs.csv file contains the correct identity values for the distribution lists? You might want to add some code to your script to help identify the problem. Suggest you add the following line before Get-DistributionGroupMember:  

  Write-Output "Checking $($DL.Name)" 

This will write the name of each distribution list to the output so you can determine if the correct values are being read from the DLs.csv file.

Comment: added the suggested line:
# Get List of Distribution Group Members
 Write-Output "Checking $($DL.Name)"
    $GroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL -ResultSize Unlimited


csv looks like:

DistributionLists
dl1-name
dl2-name
dl3-name

Output:
Getting same error but now it has the word 'Checking' in front of each error.

Comment: added error screenshot at the end of my question above.

Comment: #identity is returning entire row - need to get to just the name
# $GroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL -ResultSize Unlimited

#Change to: $DL.DistributionLists where distribution lists is the name of the column header

$GroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $DL.DistributionLists -ResultSize Unlimited

Comment: Just looked at the screenshot saying it can't convert because Identity is empty. 

To resolve the issue, you need to ensure that the values in the DistributionLists column of the CSV file are not empty, and that they match the names of valid distribution lists in your Exchange environment.  --- hopefully the above refactor helped and the value won't be empty because you have selected the column with the name.

Comment: Bingo ! yea it was the csv's column header mismatch. works fine now but I am not sure if its checking the nested groups, will have to do some more tests. Thanks a bunch. can you edit your first answer to reflect changes so that I can accept it?

Comment: Excellent.  Yes, I modified the original post for future readers - I'm glad we were able to solve it together!  I hope you have a great day.

Comment: I tested and this script does NOT search the email in nested groups. any pointers?

Comment: iterate through checking if it is an email or a distribution list with callback function to process.  Believe the key check will be :

if ($Member.PrimarySmtpAddress -eq $UserEmail)
.... 

If ($Member.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DistributionGroup")
....